# Right way to include blog-header.php?

Tags: ajax, wp-blog-header.php

I have a voting system on a custom post which uses AJAX, and I have a file that handles the AJAX request. This file is inside a sub folder named `php` of my theme. Hence the structure is:

> ../wp-content/themes/my-theme/php/ajax-handler.php

I use the following line to include the `blog-header.php` file:

`include('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');`

This works fine, but with debug mode on, I see warnings telling me that WP failed to open the stream as the file `blog-header.php` is non-existent.

So I tried this:

`define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);`

`require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');`

Warnings gone, but $wpdb not recognized.

Any ideas on how to make this work without the warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "right way" is to not include it at all and use WordPress provided means for [AJAX in themes and plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Yes you're right about it, but I used this method when it was an emergency and I found it easier, but now that module is an integral part of a big system. Seems like I'm gonna have to use WP-AJAX after all! Thanks!